# For MariaDB, is it necessary to create and close a connection on every function I use?

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7, mariadb

im have some doubts about good practicing about MariaDB connections uses, i have created a library with some functions, so i create connection/Create cursor/.../close cursor/close connection each Function as it follow:

```
def Func1():
    cnx=mariadb.connect(host,user,pass,db)
    cursor=cnx.cursor()
    do...Query and something else
    cnx.commit()
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()

def Func 2():
    cnx=mariadb.connect(host,user,pass,db)
    cursor=cnx.cursor()
    do...Query and something else
    cnx.commit()
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
...
def FuncN():
    cnx=mariadb
    ....
    cnx.close()

Main:
    Func1()
    Func2()
... FuncN()
```

and i would like to know if i can save some lines  doing something like this:

```
cnx=mariadb.connect(host,user,pass,db)
cursor=cnx.cursor()

def Func1():
    do...Query and something else
def Func2():
    do...Query and something else
....
Main:
    Func1()
    Func2()
    ....FuncN()
    cnx.commit()
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
```

i just want to figure out how i can do my code shorter, im using python 2 by now btw...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In any programming language, you should connect once and (optionally) disconnect once.

You need some way of using a global variable, singleton object, or otherwise avoid doing two connections.

There are cases where two connections is warranted, but they are very rare.

Usually the platform (eg, web server) will do the disconnect if you fail to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i gonna take your advice and modify my code; btw at least for MariaDB connect and disconnect few times (in my code 7 times) works fine i do this each minute for two weeks. but i think is better the way you explain

Comment: If your program runs for 14 days, then there is a good chance that a network hiccup will cause a disconnection unexpectedly.  So, be ready to reconnect if this happens.